# Adding a custom button to the OneNote ribbon

Tags: script, autohotkey, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

Is there any way to add a simple custom button to the OneNote 2016 ribbon? All I want to do is have it run an AutoHotKey script. I looked at Onetastic but it does not appear to have a way to run external programs and scripts.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't start autohotkey script this way, but there are a lot of functions available to select from,  and also you can call a vba macro.

Comment: If you can call a VBA macro then you can run an AutoHotkey script from it, but I don't think you can actually call a vba macro from the OneNote Ribbon (without a custom add-in that has its own Ribbon interface)

Comment: @JJohnston2: yes it's possible to call VBA, see e.g. [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-ribbon-3c610b47-6f0f-4179-83d3-68a254a80ea6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=4#__toc323203887) under "add commands to a custom group).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to add a simple custom button to the OneNote 2016
>   ribbon? All I want to do is have it run an AutoHotKey script. I looked
>   at Onetastic but it does not appear to have a way to run external
>   programs and scripts.

Is there a specific reason that you're needing to add a button to the ribbon?
AutoHotkey lets you do anything with any key combo. You can also make it so the hotkey only works in OneNote.

Here's an example of setting an F1 hotkey to one note. If you press F1 in any other program, it'll function normally. If you press it inside of one note, you'll get a message box popup instead.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe onenote.exe

F1::MsgBox, You'll only see this message box if you press F1 while in One Note.

#if
```

I know this isn't exactly what you were looking for, but it does offer a solution to your general problem of wanting to launch an AHK script from One Note.

---

References:
[#IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)

Comment: It can't be a key combo because I'm looking for a solution when I am using a touch screen and no keyboard.

Comment: So apparently I don't get notifications on responses. :( Normally I don't wait 3 weeks to comment back.

I know that tablets like the surface pro have a way to detect touchscreen specific things like "triple finger tap". You can capture the vk (virtual key) and sc (scan code) of these actions and turn them into hotkeys. Instructions can be found at https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/4f4j9k/read_this_before_posting/. Look under "Finding Out What Button You're Pressing (JoyPad, Random Keyboard Keys, Surface Pro Stylus, etc...)"

You can also post questions to that subreddit.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create/add buttons and entire ribbons to the Office interface.

No, it is not necessarily simple.

MSDN has extensive documentation on the subject. This will be the place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx

Comment: OP asks about calling an autohotkey script from onenote,  how your question answers it?

Comment: OP is asking how to add a custom button to OneNote to accomplish something. Currently that something is in an AutoHotkey script. Whether he can eventually call the AHK script or has to rewrite that or package it a different way in order to be called, he'll have to add a button to the Ribbon, which is possible, but requires a decent amount of development effort, especially for a non-programmer.

Comment: Your comment was "no". My answer was "yes, but".

Comment: What you've explained is not obvious from your answer. It more seems like a link only answer with some comments.  Please edit it.